# eliminating duplicate values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was wondering what is the best way to eliminate duplicates within an array? Currently I'm running through a foreach loop to actually get this array, is there a way to say, if `id` already exists, don't insert into array?

```
foreach($categories2Sugg as $Category2Sugg)
{

    $category_stringArray2Sugg[] = array("id"=>$Category2Sugg->id,"name"=>$Category2Sugg->name,"pluralName"=>$Category2Sugg->pluralName,"shortName"=>$Category2Sugg->shortName);      

}


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d16c941735
            [name] => Burger Joint
            [pluralName] => Burger Joints
            [shortName] => Burgers
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d16c941735
            [name] => Burger Joint
            [pluralName] => Burger Joints
            [shortName] => Burgers
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d16c941735
            [name] => Burger Joint
            [pluralName] => Burger Joints
            [shortName] => Burgers
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d14e941735
            [name] => American Restaurant
            [pluralName] => American Restaurants
            [shortName] => American
        )
)
```

Or maybe its easier to do another function if this array already exists, just delete some values to output a new array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [array_unique](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) php function that will help.

Also Try

```
$unique = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array)));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($unique);
echo "</pre>";
```

Above code is tested.

**Complete Tested Code**

```
<?php
$array = array
(
    '0' => array
    (
        'id' => '4bf58dd8d48988d16c941735',
        'name' => 'Burger Joint',
        'pluralName' => 'Burger Joints',
        'shortName' => 'Burgers'
    ),
    '1' => array
    (
        'id' => '4bf58dd8d48988d16c941735',
        'name' => 'Burger Joint',
        'pluralName' => 'Burger Joints',
        'shortName' => 'Burgers'
    ),
    '2' => array
    (
        'id' => '4bf58dd8d48988d16c941735',
        'name' => 'Burger Joint',
        'pluralName' => 'Burger Joints',
        'shortName' => 'Burgers'
    ),
    '3' => array
    (
        'id' => '4bf58dd8d48988d14e941735',
        'name' => 'American Restaurant',
        'pluralName' => 'American Restaurants',
        'shortName' => 'American'
    )
);

$unique = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $array)));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($unique);
?>
```

Cheers.

Comment: i have updated my answer please take a look, i have also tested it.